Correct way to Mock IFileSystemWatcher with IFileSystem
I've created a simple class that has a IFileSystem structure and a file which is tracked through IFileSystemWatcher. I'm trying to create mock tests for it, but somehow OnChanged doesn't get triggered through the mock test when I delete the file.
using System.IO.Abstractions;

public class TestFileWatcher
{
    private readonly IFileSystemWatcher _fileWatcher;
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    public bool isDeleted = false;

    public TestFileWatcher(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
        _fileWatcher = _fileSystem.FileSystemWatcher.CreateNew();

        AddFileWatch("deleteFile");
    }

    private void AddFileWatch(string path)
    {
        _fileWatcher.Path = _fileSystem.Path.GetDirectoryName(path); 
        _fileWatcher.Filter = _fileSystem.Path.GetFileName(path);

        _fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                    | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;

        _fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        _fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        _fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        _fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        fi.Refresh();
        isDeleted = true;
    }

}

Here is the mock test:
using System.IO.Abstractions;
using System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

[Collection("Sequential")]
public class MockTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Mock_TestFileWatcher()
    {
        var _mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcherFactory()
        };
        _mockFileSystem.AddFile("deleteFile", new MockFileData(""));

        var test = new Mock<TestFileWatcher>(_mockFileSystem).Object;
        _mockFileSystem.File.Delete("deleteFile");
        Assert.True(test.isDeleted);
    }
}

This works fine in an actual file structure, but somehow doesn't in the mock. Think it might be due to how the FileSystemWatcherFactory is created in the mock, but I'm unsure on how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Can you provide more details to help reproduce? It looks like the IFileSystemWatcherFactory interface from the System.IO.Abstractions package lacks a CreateNew() method. FileSystemWatcherFactory has a constructor that takes a fileSystem parameter. Are you using a different package, or is the code you posted not actually the code that you're seeing this behavior from?

@StriplingWarrior, I've modified the code with reference, de-compiled assembly code shows 3 overloaded CreateNew() methods. I've been able to reproduce the issues with this code. (isDeleted is not updated)

It looks like those methods were obsoleted and eventually removed: https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions/commit/4733ab5cf346237b93add6fc48714b07f2c3ea81

And in the latest version it appears the MockFileSystem will not allow you to set the FileSystemWatcher property. This looks like the expected pattern, where you have to create your own class that extends the MockFileSystem.
